# Check if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: android, ruby, rspec, capybara, appium

I am trying to write a test that checks if a checkbox is checked or not, if not checked what method will I use to have it checked.

I already have written a code that checks a checkbox,

```
driver.find_element(:id, 'id_of_the_element').click();
```

but I still want to check if it was checked or not also for other test case

TYIA!

Comment: idk about what you're using, but in Android the function is called isChecked(), perhaps check your docs

Comment: @SaikCaskey, I am using ruby and capybara to write my test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are expecting the code snippet in Ruby since wrote the snippet for ruby.This code works if you want to check the unchecked checkbox. You can modify if you need more changes inside that.

```
    element=driver.find_element(:id, 'id_of_the_element');
    if(element.attribute("checked")=="false")
    {
        element.click();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if((cb.isChecked())
{
  //Checkbox is true.
}
else
{
  //Checkbox is false.
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To check if the checkbox is checked or not you have to call the [`isChecked()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html#isChecked()) method like this:

```
if(checkbox.isChecked()) {
    // The checkbox is checked
} else {
    // The checkbox isn't checked
}
```

While to set the state of the checkbox you have to call the [`setChecked()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html#setChecked(boolean)) method passing in as parameter `true` to check it and `false` to uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using Capybara with appium, but for some reason you're calling driver specific methods rather than using the normal Capybara API
. Instead of the `driver.find_element(:id, 'id_of_the_element').click();` you should just be calling either of

```
page.find(:id, 'id_of_the_element').click() # use the id selector
page.find('#id_of_the_element').click() # use default CSS with an id selector
```

to find and click an element with id 'id_of_the_element'.  When dealing with specific element types there are other methods available though, so for checkboxes we have `check` and `uncheck` - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#check-instance_method - will will check or uncheck a checkbox, while checking whether it is already checked/unchecked. So

```
page.check('id_of_the_element)
```

will make sure an <input type="checkbox" id='id_of_the_element> element is left in the checked state, whatever the state was before.

If you still need to check whether or not a checkbox is checked - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#checked%3F-instance_method - you can use any of

```
page.find('#id_of_the_element').checked? # return checked state of any element
page.find(:checkbox, 'id_of_the_element').checked? # will only find actual checkbox elements
page.find_field('id_of_the_element', type: 'checkbox').checked?
...
```

or if you want to assert that a checkbox is checked any of the following will do that - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:checkbox, 'id_of_the_element', checked: true)
expect(page).to have_field('id_of_the_element', type: 'checkbox', checked: true)
expect(page).to have_checked_field('id_of_the_element')
```

Comment: When I tried to use the page.find method, it is listing all the elements id's available on that page but unable to locate the element. but page.find_element works somehow. I think I have to read all the documentation that you have given me. Thanks!

Comment: @Aurb Then it sounds like you're not actually using Capybara with Appium, and should remove the Capybara tag from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think is much simplier... (With python will be like this)

```
def isChecked(self, webElement):
    if webElement.get_attribute("checked") == 'true':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```